# Non integrated change lists between two branches

Tags: perl, perforce

when I use the following command in command line it's giving list of non integrated change lists.

```
p4 interchanges -t $branch1 @$date1, @$date2 $branch2 > changes.txt
```

But when I use this command in a Perl script as below it's not giving output:

```
$cmd = system ("p4 interchanges -t $branch1 @$date1, @$date2 $branch2 > changes.txt");
```

The output message in commandline is some error as given below:

```
branch1, - all revision(s) already integrated.
```

The issue is because of the comma used between date1 and date2? How to use this command in a Perl script?

Comment: c'wiki'd for fear of being downvoted?

Comment: @Zaid: self-fulfilling prophecy.

Answer (score 7):

This is why it is so important to turn on the [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas.  The string "@$date1" does not mean what you think it does.  It is trying to dereference `$data1` as a an array.  Because `strict` isn't on it is treating the contents of `$date1` as a symbolic reference.  If you had turned on `strict` you would have seen an error message like:

```
Can't use string ("2010-08-30") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at script.pl line 10.
```

You should probably say this instead:

```
system "p4 interchanges -t $branch1\@$date1,\@$date2 $branch2 > changes.txt";
if ($?) {
    die "saw exit code: ", $? >> 8;
}
```

You may also have a problem if you expect `$branch1`, `$date1`, etc. to be shell variables instead of Perl variables.  In that case you should say:

```
system "p4 interchanges -t $ENV{branch1}\@$ENV{date1},\@$ENV{date2} $ENV{branch2} > changes.txt";
if ($?) {
    die "saw exit code: ", $? >> 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing a lot of Perforce with Perl, try the [P4Perl](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/02_perl.html), which wraps Perforce in a Perl-native API.

Cribbing from the documentation, your `system()` call could be implemented as:

```
use P4;
my $p4 = new P4;
$p4->SetClient( $clientname );
$p4->SetPort ( $p4port );
$p4->SetPassword( $p4password );
$p4->Connect() or die( "Failed to connect to Perforce Server" );

my $c = $p4->Run( "interchanges", "-t", $branch1, "@".$date1, "@".$date2, $branch2 );
```

`$c` will contain an array reference with each of the unintegrated changelists.